# if statement condition in an if statement condition

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with an if statement where I want to add another condition if user is admin on top of whether vm.model.purchaseDate is not empty like so

Need some pseudo code to explain it

```
if(vm.model.purchaseDate && (vm.user.admin then also if(anotherCondition))) {
   //do something1
   //do something2
   //do something3
   //do something4
} else {
   //do something else
}
```

So if `vm.model.purchaseDate` is defined and user is NOT `vm.user.admin` then ignore `anotherCondition`. If user is `vm.user.admin` then also check `anotherCondition`.

I don't want to end up writing lots of ifs when my //do something code is pretty long. Trying to avoid this

```
if(vm.model.purchaseDate) {
   if(vm.user.admin) {
      if(anotherCondition) {
         //do something1
         //do something2
         //do something3
         //do something4
       }
   } else {
      //do something1
      //do something2
      //do something3
      //do something4
   }
} else {
   //do something else
}
```

Comment: `vm.model.purchaseDate && (!vm.user.admin || anotherCondition)`

Comment: It's interesting that if a user is an admin, you're restricting what they can do more than if they aren't an admin...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use OR (`||`) with `!vm.user.admin` and `anotherCondition`:

```
if(vm.model.purchaseDate && (!vm.user.admin || anotherCondition)) {
   //do something1
   //do something2
   //do something3
   //do something4
} else {
   //do something else
}
```

That way:

- If the user is not an admin, `!vm.user.admin` is `true` and the `||` takes `true` as its result
- If the user is an admin, `!vm.user.admin` is `false` and so `||` takes the result of evaluating `anotherCondition` as its result

Comment: @DavidB - I don't think the OP wants to, does he/she?

Comment: `if(vm.model.purchaseDate || vm.user.admin && anotherCondition)`? or am I stupid? And I think you have a `)` too much

Comment: @Elias - Thanks on the `)`, editing error. :-) No, your reworking of it wouldn't do (what I understand to be) what the OP wants. They used `&&`, so they must want `vs.model.purchaseDate` to be a requirement regardless of the second operand.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder exactly. If user is not admin, don't bother checking anotherCondition.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Awh okay :) I was expecting `admin` to be an overwrite. Nice anwer, good and clear!